# Get CheckboxGridPanel selected rows values, ext.net C#?

Tags: c#, ext.net

I'm using Ext.net 1.2 == ExtJs 3.4.0

I wanna add the selected values (Filter with Name, Lname) to an ext's textbox.
I searched , and I could find the below codes, but now I don't know how I can add the the values from var values in JavaScript to an ext's textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddUser() {
        var values = GridPanel1.getRowsValues(
        {
            filterField: function (record, fieldName, value) {return fieldName == "Name" || fieldName == "Lname";},
            selectedOnly: true,
            currentPageOnly: false
        });
        ////this method should be complete
    }
</script>

<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server" OnRefreshData="Store1_RefreshData">
        <Reader>
            <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="ID">
                <Fields>
                    <ext:RecordField Name="ID" Type="Int" />
                    <ext:RecordField Name="RowNumber" Type="Int" />
                    <ext:RecordField Name="Name" />
                    <ext:RecordField Name="Lname" />
                    <ext:RecordField Name="EnterprisePosition" />
                </Fields>
            </ext:JsonReader>
        </Reader>
    </ext:Store>
    <br />
    <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" StoreID="Store1" StripeRows="true"
        Title="Result" Collapsible="true" StyleSpec="width:95%; margin:0 auto;"
        Height="350" Collapsed="true">
        <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column ColumnID="RowNumber" Header="Row" Width="50" Resizable="false" MenuDisabled="true"
                    Fixed="true" DataIndex="RowNumber" />
                <ext:Column ColumnID="Name" Header="Name" Width="100" DataIndex="Name" />
                <ext:Column Header="Last Name" Width="150" DataIndex="Lname" />
                <ext:Column Header="Position" Width="160" DataIndex="EnterprisePosition" />
            </Columns>
        </ColumnModel>
        <BottomBar>
            <ext:PagingToolbar ID="PagingToolBar1" runat="server" PageSize="10" StoreID="Store1"
                DisplayInfo="false" />
        </BottomBar>
        <SelectionModel>
            <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel ID="CheckboxSelectionModel1" runat="server">
                <Listeners>
                    <RowSelect Fn="AddUser" /><!-- ******** -->
                </Listeners>
            </ext:CheckboxSelectionModel>
        </SelectionModel>
    </ext:GridPanel>
</div>
```

How should I do it ?

Comment: I don't see any textbox in your code?
Usually, you can do next: textbox.setValue(values[0]); 
I don't know what contains variable values, can you debug it in Firebug and print here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?152859-Get-CheckboxGridPanel-selected-rows-values-v3.4.0&p=666495&viewfull=1#post666495).
The complete function is the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddUser() {
        Ext.getCmp('TextFieldReceivers').setValue("");
        var count = Ext.getCmp('GridPanel1').getSelectionModel().getCount();
        var lst = Ext.getCmp('GridPanel1').getSelectionModel().getSelections();
        var textfiled = Ext.getCmp('TextFieldReceivers');
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            textfiled.setValue(textfiled.value + lst[i].data.Name + " " + lst[i].data.Lname + ",");
        }
    }
</script>
```